# How do I set up this countdown with php and ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a perpetual countdown timer I need to set up and I am struggling with how to do it properly.

I am using a plugin called coutdown which can be found here:

http://www.littlewebthings.com/projects/countdown/

So my setup so far involves the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#countdown_contain').countDown({
        targetDate: {
            'day':      23,
            'month':    6,
            'year':     2013,
            'hour':     12,
            'min':      0,
            'sec':      0
        },
        omitWeeks: true
    });
});
```

So what that is doing is counting down to Sunday June 23 of 2013. When it gets to zero I need it to reset and then start counting down to the same time in two weeks. So basically I need a two week countdown timer for Sundays at noon.

My thought is to perhaps make an ajax call to a php script every time the page loads to see where we are at compared to the next countdown date, then populate the response into JS variables that will become the info the plugin uses. Perhaps that is too much?

How would I structure my php or javascript to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of ajax, I would create a javascript functions that calculate the next valid day, and use that to seed the counter time.  That way, there's no additional server interaction.

As far as resetting automatically, use the `onComplete` event to reseed the control.

---

to dynamically build a targetDate structure, I'd do something like this using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/).  Note that this I coded to theory during a "nonsmoker's smokebreak" at work, so this is untested.  Please edit, don't downvote if it doesn't work 100%.

```
function getTargetDate() {
     // initialize the static stuff...
     var retval = { 'hour':12,'min':0,'sec':0 }
     // good news! using Moment.js in the USA, Sunday is considered first day of week
     // so all we have to do is calculate the correct week number...
     var currentWeekOfYear = moment().week(); 
     // assume that we're targeting odd weeks, so 
     //  if it's odd, add 2, if it's even, add 1
     var nextTargetWeek = currentWeekOfYear;
     if( currentWeekOfYear % 2 == 0) {
         nextTargetWeek += 1;
     } else {
         nextTargetWeek += 2;
     }

     var nextTarget = moment().week(nextTargetWeek);

     // moment retains the current day, so we need to set it to sunday.
     nextTarget = nextTarget.day(0);

     // now, enrich the return value
     retval.day = nextTarget.date();
     retval.month = nextTarget.month();
     retval.year = nextTarget.year();

     return retval;
}
```

Comment: Can you offer any insight as the best way to calculate the next valid day through JS? I could start an additional question too.

Comment: If I were solving this completely with javascript, which is completely doable, I would find a decent javascript date library.

Comment: Agree.  Was researching some and looking at moment.js

Comment: Yep this works perfect and really pointed me in the right direction, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an exact answer but it should put you on the right track.

You can just echo the variables directly into your javascript file.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#countdown_contain').countDown({
    targetDate: {
        'day':      <?php echo(json_encode($day)); ?>,
        'month':    <?php echo(json_encode($month)); ?>,
        'year':     <?php echo(json_encode($year)); ?>,
        'hour':     <?php echo(json_encode($hour)); ?>,
        'min':      <?php echo(json_encode($min)); ?>,
        'sec':      <?php echo(json_encode($sec)); ?>
    },
    omitWeeks: true
});
});
```

In your php script, you can use [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)  to calculate the next target day.